# Documents directory in objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsdocument

In Xcode, the Resources folder links to the NSDocumentsFolder of the app? Or what else?

Is there a way to see the files in NSDocumentFolder without write code?

Answer (score 0):

No the resource folder in Xcode does not link to the document directory, it is just imaginary folder for organization in xcode. However there you could see the content of your document directory by browsing to the folder in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

The folders you use in XCode will not be copied to your application bundle even though all their content (as well as anything else you have in your XCode project...excluding compiled resources) will be flatly copied into your Bundle Folder. If what you need is accessing the Documents folder on an iOS app or in a the User's library you can access it (by code, I'm sorry) with:

```
NSString *documentFolderPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
```

And anything you need to be in there you will have to copy by code.